# How do I set up dnsmasq for loopback to a local machine?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I recently changed my ISP and discovered a few days ago that I can't access from other computers or gadgets connected to the same home network, a domain I'm self-hosting (linked via a DDNS provider) on a local machine. It doesn't matter whether I use the full url [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or the the wired card's IP 192.168.0.xx or the wi-fi's 192.168.0.xy from within the network. I **can** get the site from the host machine using the FQDN [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I'm running Apache with virtual hosts on Ubuntu 20.10 and have set in /etc/hosts 192.168.0.xx [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and 192.168.0.xx example.com.

From Web searches I discovered that my ISP's Hitron CODA router does not support NAT loopback as opposed to the old router of the previous provider that caused no issues with access within or outside the network.

My search suggested that running a DNS server on the host machine could produce a solution and it seems that dnsmasq is a less cumbersome server to install and configure than Bind9.

**How can I install and configure dnsmasq to achieve my goal of maintaining access from outside to the domain while adding the ability to reach it from any computer or gadget within the network?**

Running `systemd-resolve --status` output:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no            
MulticastDNS setting: no            
  DNSOverTLS setting: no            
      DNSSEC setting: no            
    DNSSEC supported: no            
          DNS Domain: hitronhub.home

Link 2 (enp4s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                            
DefaultRoute setting: yes                            
       LLMNR setting: yes                            
MulticastDNS setting: no                             
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                             
      DNSSEC setting: no                             
    DNSSEC supported: no                             
  Current DNS Server: 2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5204
         DNS Servers: 2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5204
                      2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5198
                      192.168.0.1                    
          DNS Domain: ~.                             
                      hitronhub.home                 

Link 3 (wlxa0f3c10adaa1)
```

Running `networkctl status enp0s3` output
`WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.`

The content of /etc/resolv.conf:

Generated by NetworkManager

search hitronhub.home

nameserver 127.0.0.53

Is what I am contemplating possible? I have not yet installed dnsmasq for fear of breaking anything.

Thanks.